# Transforming django project into a django application

Tags: django, project, django-apps

Is it wise to add `models`, `views` and other **"django application related files"** in the project directory, then specifying the project name in the **INSTALLED_APPS** ?

What is the best way to define a **"main application"**?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this pattern:

- the project contains settings, but no models and no views.
- the project uses several apps
- apps have models and views.

This way, you don't need to insert the project into `INSTALLED_APPS`.